# In Angular 4, I am able to inject a dependency in my app.module, However it's giving me error in other component

Tags: angular, typescript

app.module.ts

```
import { ProductService } from './shared/product.service'
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   ProductionComponent
 ],
 imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   BrowserAnimationsModule,
   AppRoutes
  ],
  providers: [ProductService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

in component production.component.ts i get an error,could you tell me why?

```
export class ProductionComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private productService:ProductService) { }   //throw error: Cannot find name 'ProductService'

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to import it to your `production.component.ts` too in order to let typescript know where to refer `ProductService`, mention that you may need to change the path if your `app.module.ts` and `production.component.ts` are not in the same folder.

```
import { ProductService } from './shared/product.service';   // <--import here in order to refer to it

export class ProductionComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private productService:ProductService) { }   //throw error: Cannot find name 'ProductService'

  }
}
```

Comment: Think you.So,if i inject some dependencives in my app module,I just import them to my components,need not to set provides in my components.Think you very much

Comment: @user8408794 this is syntax for typescript. Typescript needs to know where to refer the data-type(here the ProductService).

Answer (score 0):

in production.component.ts page you also have to add that server to use.
your code should be like:

```
import { ProductService } from './shared/product.service';
export class ProductionComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private productService:ProductService) { }
  }
}
```

It should work now.